lm-sensors partially uses a custom config
Ubuntu 22.04, lm-sensors 3.6.0
I put the custom config in /etc/sensors.d/.
The lines that exist in /etc/sensors3.conf override my config.
That is, in /etc/sensors.d/my_config.conf I wrote:
set in1_min 2.5
set in1_max 3.5

Then I applied the sudo sensors -s. Some of the set parameters were applied and some were not.
So the output of sensors -u:
set in1_min 2.7
set in1_max 3.63

Because in /etc/sensors3.conf it says:
set in1_min 3*0.9
set in1_max 3,3*1,1

How to make it so that the custom config is used completely? And /etc/sensors3.conf is ignored when using sensors.
And an additional question regarding this topic.
Why, after rebooting the system, does the sensors give wrong readings until I apply sudo sensors -s?
How can I make it so that after a system reboot, the sensor output immediately uses the custom config?
